# Accept arbitrary arguments and options with Click

Tags: python-3.x, python-click

I'm writing a Python wrapper around another program.  I want the user to be able to specify a few options for the wrapper and then pass the rest of the command-line through to the wrapped program.  Something like this:

```
@click.command()
@click.option("--port", type=int)
@click.argument("args", nargs=-1)
def main(port, args):
    call_the_wrapped_program(port=port, args=args)
```

But this dies with `Error: no such option: -k` because it treats any command-line switch as something it should parse rather than an argument that can be added to `args`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

The [Forwarding Unknown Options](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/advanced/#forwarding-unknown-options) section in the documentation covers this use case. You should be able to write something like this:

```py
@click.command(context_settings=dict(
    ignore_unknown_options=True,
))
@click.option("--port", type=int)
@click.argument("args", nargs=-1, type=click.UNPROCESSED)
def main(port, args):
    call_the_wrapped_program(port=port, args=args)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you invoke the program with something akin to a cli command, have you tried simply calling it like this?

```sh
cli --port 8080 -- -k arg1 arg2 -r etc
```

If I print args with that invocation, I get all the arguments out, albeit as a string, but I'm hoping that whatever third party you want to delegate to might be able to run its own parsing over that.

Comment: I think the comment above is according to conventions. If you would like to create (`touch`) a file through cli named "-k", then `touch -k` and `touch "-k"` and `touch '-k'` won't work. Instead, `touch -- -k` does work.